# Swift XML attribute parsing

Tags: xml, swift, parsing, attributes

I have problem with XML parsing in Swift. I woul like to use `AttributeDict` but i have many attributes to use it. So i use `Dictionary`. But it's not working, 
And i use code in this page:

[Get attibuteDict of a subclass Xml parsing - Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30820024/get-attibutedict-of-a-subclass-xml-parsing-swift)

but it's still not working. Tell me if you know
 My XML Data:

```
 <root>
        <day1><day1 p1.1="-" pk1.1="-" s1.1="" a1.1="-" p1.2="-" pk1.2="-" s1.2="" a1.2="-" 
        p1.3="Начертательная геометрия и компьютерная графика" pk1.3="НГиКГ" s1.3="Оспанова З. К." 
        a1.3="127 ГМК" p1.4="Начертательная геометрия и компьютерная графика" pk1.4="НГиКГ" 
        s1.4="Оспанова З. К." a1.4="127 ГМК" p1.5="Физика" pk1.5="Физика" s1.5="Сарсембаева Б. Д." 
        a1.5="913 ГУК" p1.6="Физика" pk1.6="Физика" s1.6="Сарсембаева Б. Д." a1.6="1035 с ГУК" 
        p1.7="Физика" pk1.7="Физика" s1.7="Сарсембаева Б. Д." a1.7="913а ГУК" p1.8="Физика" 
        pk1.8="Физика" s1.8="Сарсембаева Б. Д." a1.8="913а ГУК" p1.9="Физическая культура" 
        pk1.9="ФизКульт" s1.9="Акмалиев А. Ж." a1.9=" -" p1.10="Физическая культура" pk1.10="ФизКульт" 
        s1.10="Акмалиев А. Ж." a1.10=" -" p1.11="-" pk1.11="-" s1.11="" a1.11="-" p1.12="-" pk1.12="-" 
        s1.12="" a1.12="-" p2.1="-" pk2.1="-" s2.1="" a2.1="-" p2.2="Политология" pk2.2="Полит-ия" 
        s2.2="Анапияева Г. Б." a2.2="705 ГУК" p2.3="Физика" pk2.3="Физика" s2.3="Оспанов К. М." 
        a2.3="713 ГУК" p2.4="Физика" pk2.4="Физика" s2.4="Оспанов К. М." a2.4="713 ГУК" 
        p2.5="Начертательная геометрия и компьютерная графика" pk2.5="НГиКГ" s2.5="Оспанова З. К." 
        a2.5="1035в ГУК" p2.6="Начертательная геометрия и компьютерная графика" pk2.6="НГиКГ" 
        s2.6="Оспанова З. К." a2.6="1035в ГУК" p2.7="Физическая культура" pk2.7="ФизКульт" s2.7="Акмалиев А. Ж." 
        a2.7=" -" p2.8="Физическая культура" pk2.8="ФизКульт" s2.8="Акмалиев А. Ж." a2.8=" -" p2.9="-" 
        pk2.9="-" s2.9="" a2.9="-" p2.10="-" pk2.10="-" s2.10="" a2.10="-" p2.11="-" pk2.11="-" s2.11="" a2.11="-"
        p2.12="-" pk2.12="-" s2.12="" a2.12="-" p3.1="-" pk3.1="-" s3.1="" a3.1="-" p3.2="-" pk3.2="-" s3.2="" a3.2="-"
        p3.3="Математика II" pk3.3="Матем.II" s3.3="Акимжанова Ш. А." a3.3="713 ГУК" p3.4="Математика II" 
        pk3.4="Матем.II" s3.4="Акимжанова Ш. А." a3.4="713 ГУК" p3.5="Начертательная геометрия и компьютерная графика" 
        pk3.5="НГиКГ" s3.5="Иисова А. М." a3.5="533 ГУК" p3.6="Эдвайзер" pk3.6="ЭД" s3.6="Тирижанова М. Б." 
        a3.6="517 ВК" p3.7="Начертательная геометрия и компьютерная графика" pk3.7="НГиКГ" s3.7="Курманалиева Ш. М." 
        a3.7="805 ГУК" p3.8="Начертательная геометрия и компьютерная графика" pk3.8="НГиКГ" s3.8="Курманалиева Ш. М." 
        a3.8="805 ГУК" p3.9="Начертательная геометрия и компьютерная графика" pk3.9="НГиКГ" s3.9="Курманалиева Ш. М." 
        a3.9="708 ГУК" p3.10="Начертательная геометрия и компьютерная графика" pk3.10="НГиКГ" 
        s3.10="Курманалиева Ш. М." a3.10="708 ГУК" p3.11="-" pk3.11="-" s3.11="" a3.11="-" p3.12="-" 
        pk3.12="-" s3.12="" a3.12="-"></day1>
        </day1>
    </root>
```

And my not working Code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

func parser = NSXMLParser()
var schedule = NSDictionary()
var elements = NSMutableDictionary()
var element = NSString()

func beginParsing()
{
   parser = NSXMLParser(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: "SomeUrl")!)! 
   parser.delegate = self
   parser.parse()
}

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser!, didStartElement elementName: String!, namespaceURI: String!, qualifiedName qName: String!, attributes attributeDict: [NSObject : AnyObject]!)
{
   element = elementName
   if (elementName as NSString).isEqualToString("day1")
   {
       //name of subject
       schedule = [p1.1="-", pk1.1="", s1.1="", a1.1="", p1.2="", pk1.2="",
       s1.2="", a1.2="", p1.3="",  pk1.3="", s1.3="", 
       a1.3="", p1.4="", pk1.4="", 
       s1.4="", a1.4="", p1.5="", pk1.5="", s1.5="", 
       a1.5="", p1.6="", pk1.6="", s1.6="", a1.6="", 
       p1.7="", pk1.7="", s1.7="", a1.7="", p1.8="", 
       pk1.8="", s1.8="", a1.8="", p1.9="", 
       pk1.9="", s1.9="", a1.9="", p1.10="", pk1.10="", 
       s1.10="", a1.10=""]

       elements = NSMutableDictionary()
       elements = [:]

  }
}

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser!, foundCharacters string: NSString!)
{
   if element.isEqualToString("day1") {
   func parser(parser: NSXMLParser!, didStartElement elementName: String!, namespaceURI: String!, qualifiedName: String!, attributes: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {

           element = elementName
           if (elementName as NSString).isEqual("day1") {

           }
       }
   }
} 


func parser(parser: NSXMLParser!, didEndElement elementName: String!, namespaceURI: String!, qualifiedName qName: String!)
{
   if (elementName as NSString).isEqualToString("day1") {
      print(schedule)
   }`
```

And i don't create this XML data, this XML data give me my university

Comment: You have two `day1` XML elements, one without attributes and one with. Does your XML really have both? This XML doesn't make sense. If you have two different elements with the same name, you're making life unnecessarily confusing.

Comment: yes, it's two "day1", so I do not know how to parse the data

Comment: I'm also unclear regarding your naming convention for attributes within the `day1` element. Your `didStartElement` suggests that you're only interested in the `p1.*`, `pk1.*`, `s1.*`, and `a1.*` tags, even though your XML has a lot more attributes within the `day1` element. Do you want all of the attributes under the inner `day1` tag, or only some?

Comment: I want all attributes, and distribute them in the table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of observations:

1. Your `didStartElement` should simply look at `attributeDict` to get the attributes for an element.
2. You don't need a `foundCharacters` method in this case, because you're only parsing elements tags, and not parsing anything between the open and close tags.
3. The `foundCharacters` method, if you even needed it, shouldn't have a private `didStartElement` implemented within it.
4. The only trick in your example is that you have very confusing XML with nested `day1` tags. I'd really suggest changing the XML to something that makes sense.

   But, if you're stuck with this, one fairly flexible solution is to keep a stack of element names (implemented as simple array, `elementNames`), push an `elementName` onto the stack in `didStartElement` (by adding to the end of the array of `elementNames`) and popping one off in `didEndElement` (by calling `removeLast`). So, for example, by the time you hit the inner `day1` tag inside your XML, the array of `elementNames` will be `["root", "day1", "day1"]`.

   Now that you have that, you can check to see if you are looking at `day1` inside another `day1` by seeing if the last two items in `elementNames` are both `day1`.

For example:

```
func beginParsing(URL: NSURL) {
    let parser = NSXMLParser(contentsOfURL: URL)!
    parser.delegate = self
    parser.parse()
    print(schedule)
}

var schedule: [String: String]?
var elementNames = [String]()

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String]) {
    elementNames.append(elementName)
    let count = elementNames.count

    if count >= 2 && elementNames[count - 2] == "day1" && elementNames[count - 1] == "day1" {
        schedule = attributeDict
    }
}

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {
    elementNames.removeLast()
}

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, parseErrorOccurred parseError: NSError) {
    print(parseError)
}
```

Comment: thank you, i try this code,one more question how to make to select some of them to insert into the table

Comment: I tried to use this code, but it does not show anything

Answer (score 0):

```
Use this class for Parse XML data with the help of SWXMLHash xml parser in Swift language.

https://github.com/drmohundro/SWXMLHash


import UIKit

public struct ParseMyXMLApis {

    //MARK:- Parsing API here
    public static func getparseMyApi(input: String, action:String, completion: (result: String, error: NSError?) -> Void) {

        //Main API here
        let is_URL: String = "Enter your url here"

        let lobj_Request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: is_URL)!)
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

        lobj_Request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        lobj_Request.HTTPBody = input.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        //lobj_Request.addValue("www.cgsapi.com", forHTTPHeaderField: "Host")
        lobj_Request.addValue("text/xml; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        lobj_Request.addValue(String(input.characters.count), forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
        lobj_Request.addValue("http://tempuri.org/IService/\(action)", forHTTPHeaderField: "SOAPAction")

        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(lobj_Request, completionHandler: {(data: NSData?, response: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            print("Response: \(response)")

            // Checking here Response
        if response != nil {

            let statusCode = (response as! NSHTTPURLResponse).statusCode
            print("Success: \(statusCode)")

            // Checking here Response Status
        if statusCode == 200 {
            //Handling Data here
            if data?.length > 0 {
            let strData = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            let xmls = SWXMLHash.parse(data!)
            func enumerate(indexer: XMLIndexer, level: Int) {
                for child in indexer.children {
                    let name:String? = child.element!.name
                    print("\(level) \(name)")
                    let text = child.element!.text
                    if text?.isEmpty == false{
                        print(text)
                        // Finish here Process
                        completion(result: text!, error: nil)
                    }
                    enumerate(child, level: level + 1)
                }

             }
             enumerate(xmls, level: 0)

            }else{
                //Data nil Condition here
                completion(result:"", error:error)
            }

            //Handling Error here
            if error != nil
            {
                print("Error: " + error!.description)
                completion(result:"", error:error)
            }

          }else{
                //Invalid Status
                print("Error: " + error!.description)
                completion(result:"", error:error)
            }

         }else{
            //Response Nil then handle here
            print("Error: " + error!.description)
            completion(result:"", error:error)
         }

        })
        task.resume()
    }

    //MARK:- String To Dictionary Conversion
    public func convertStringToDictionary(text: String) -> AnyObject! {
        if let data = text.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
            do{
                let json:AnyObject = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions(rawValue: 0))
                return json
            }catch{
                print(error)
            }
        }
        return nil
    }

}
```

and Call this class

```
ParseMyXMLApis.getparseMyApi("Request here", action:"URL here", completion: { (result, error) -> Void in
                if error != nil{
                    //Handel Error here
                           }else{
                    print("Result is here\(result)")
                     }
        else
        {
            //Network Error Handling here
            print("Couldn't connect to network")
             }
      }
```