# IOS- GPX file parser.parse() The operation couldn’t be completed

Tags: ios, xml, swift, gpx

I'm feel frustrated figuring out why my code below doesn't parse the content of the GPX file given I think I have a sufficient amount of **XMLParserDelegate** delegate methods.

Here's the input GPX file first

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>  
<gpx version="1.1" creator="Xcode">
  <wpt lat="42.373734" lon="-71.178314">
    <name>A's house</name>
  </wpt>
  <wpt lat="41.094082" lon="-73.519411">
    <name>B's Office</name>
  </wpt>
  <wpt lat="42.350816" lon="-71.065578">
    <name>W Hotel</name>
  </wpt>
  <wpt lat="42.352291" lon="-71.045283">
    <name>District Hall</name>
  </wpt>
</gpx>
```

I also ensure that the GPX file's directory path is added into the project's **Bundle Resource**. Here, I'm only looking to parse the value assigned to keywords *lat* and *lon* from the element tag <*wpt*>.

---

From the quick search, I thought that from [the help here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37520944/swift-xml-attribute-parsing), I just need to get this delegate method
    `func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, ...)`. Please feel free to correct my assumption here, I think that I only need this delegate since I'm just looking for the stuff after the element tag <*wpt*>, no need for `func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, foundCharacters string: String)`

When I'm debugging the parsing, I got the `locArray` to be nil!!! So, I don't get why this following code doesn't parse the content into the array.

```
class AutoCheckInVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate, XMLParserDelegate{
.........
private var element: String?
private var locArray = [String]()
private var parser : XMLParser = XMLParser()

func beginParsing(){
    guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "TestLocations", ofType: "gpx") else {
        NSLog("Couldn't find the gpx file!!!")
        return
    }
    guard let url = URL(string: path) else {
        preconditionFailure("URL is nil!!!")
    }
    guard let parser = XMLParser(contentsOf: url) else {
        preconditionFailure("XML file is nil!!!")
    }
    parser.delegate = self
    let beParsed = parser.parse()

    if beParsed {
        NSLog("Start an event-driving parsing")
    }
    else {
        preconditionFailure("Failed to start parsing")
    }
   }

func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String] = [:]) {
    element = elementName
    /** The code doesn't execute inside the if part. Why???**/
    if (element == "wpt") {
        //create the string array from the file
        let long = attributeDict["lon"]!
        let lat = attributeDict["lat"]!
        self.curLL = "\(lat),\(long)" as String?
        debugPrint("Lon, Lat of current point is: \(String(describing: self.curLL))")
    }
}
func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) {
    let data = string.trimmingCharacters(in: NSCharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
    if (!data.isEmpty) {
        if (element == "wpt"){
            locArray[data] = self.curLL as String?
        }
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self

    beginParsing()        /*****Something wrong here!!!****/
    debugPrint("LocArray:       \(locArray)")

    for i in 0..<venue.numOfElements() {
        let venueTemp = venue.readHistory(atIndex: i)

        let para1: Parameters = [
            //Required: name, ll, and version date
            "ll": locArray[i]
  ]
}
```

Comment: Does your code reach the call to `parser.parse()`? Is the `didStartElement` delegate method being called at all?

Comment: I used step in to each line, and it actually got into this call. But I don't know why the if part isn't executed?

Comment: What is the value of `elementName`? What's the point of your `element` variable? Why not simply compare `elementName`?

Comment: Sorry for a late rep. The use of global var `element` semantically doesn't matter. But I used it because I did incorporate another function `func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, foundCharacters string: String)` to use `element`.

Comment: I edited my question detail, which I included the latter delegate of `XMLParserDelegate`, and set the flag for `parser.parse()`. And the problem is totally relied on why the parsing failed to start as it prints out that condition failure